# Regex match if X exists before Y but Y might not exist

Tags: regex

My text is something like this:

```
Stuff
#One: 
  *lots of stuff* 
  visible=true
  *lots of stuff* 
#Two: 
  *lots of stuff* 
  visible=false
  *lots of stuff* 
#Three: 
  *lots of stuff* 
  visible=true
  *lots of stuff* 
Stuff....
```

*lots of stuff* is not only lots of stuff but could also change. I need to be able to return true if "One:.... visible=true" It may either be false OR might not be there at all. The problem is that the other lines might not be there either.

Right now I have this:

```
(?:\n|.)*One:(?:\n|.)*?visible=true(?:\n|.)*
```

This works to tell if One is there or not, but if it is false then my regex just grabs a true from one of the following ones since they are formatted identically. I can't put a "#" at the end of my regex because it might not be there.

How do I say "look for 'visible=true' after '#One:' but before the next '#' only if there is a following '#'"?

I can use a non greedy capturing group to just grab whatever is after the very next "hidden=" after "#One". But then I have three results, true, false and no match. And this is slightly difficult because I am working in the android app "Tasker" which can either get groups or test a match but to do both required multiple operations. And the way tasker works makes it hard to get capture groups without clobbering my text so I need even more operations to clone my text first.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? Because it really isn't the right tool for this kind of task.

Comment: @Juhana I added to my post that I am working in the android app "Tasker" so my options for parsing text is very limited. So to answer your question, yes, as far as I am aware I need to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
\bOne:(?:(?!\n#\w+)[\s\S])*?\bvisible=true[\s\S]*?(?=\n#\w+|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/15

Comment: Look, I think [this one](https://regex101.com/r/dJ3vZ5/1) is a bit more precise. Maybe less efficient though.

Comment: @stribizhev matches the same stuff https://regex101.com/r/dJ3vZ5/2 just not grouped

Answer (score 0):

You need non-greedy anything-but-a-hash sequence -- `[^#]*?`. This also needs to be multiline and match newline chars, thus `(?ms)` flags:

```
(?ms)#One:[^#]*?visible=true
```

Here's how it works:

- https://regex101.com/r/eD0hY3/1
- https://regex101.com/r/mP2hB9/1
- https://regex101.com/r/zN1kH7/1